# Adding EmailName LookUp to subscriber send history AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to make a landing page that can return send history details for a subscriber, I can get to the point of having subscriber key, JobID, and EventDate pulling through by running LookUpOrderedRows on the _Sent data view, but if I try to pull in EmailName with a lookup, this returns a NULL - is there a way I can do this, or am I barking up the wrong tree?  Code here:

```
%%[

var @ReturnRows
set @ReturnRows = 0 /* Use 0 to get all results */

var @GetRows
set @GetRows = LookupOrderedRows("ent._Sent",@ReturnRows,"EventDate DESC","SubscriberKey", @SubsKey_Column) /* syntax of LookupOrderedRows */

var @GetRow, @GetRowCount
set @GetRowCount = rowcount(@GetRows)

if @GetRowCount > 0 then /* if search term or criteria matches with the data in the data extension then we will get 1 or more rows*/

var @GetRowNumber
for @GetRowNumber = 1 to @GetRowCount do /* FOR LOOP for each row */

set @GetRow = row(@GetRows,@GetRowNumber) /* calculate row number */

var @JobID_column
set @JobID_column = field(@GetRow,"JobID") /* display value of the column from data extension */

var @SentTime_Column
set @SentTime_Column = field(@GetRow,"EventDate") /* display value of the column from data extension */

var @EmailName_Column
set @EmailName_Column = Lookup("ent._Job", "EmailName", "JobID", @JobID_column)

]%%

Job ID : %%=v(@JobID_Column)=%% | Email Name: %%=v(@EmailName_Column)=%% |Sent Time : %%=v(@SentTime_Column)=%%
<br>

%%[ next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

<!-- If search term does not match with the data for any record in data extension -->
---- No rows found ----

%%[ endif ]%%
```

This returns the following sample row on my landing page:

```
Job ID : xxxxxx | Email Name: |Sent Time : 12/5/2017 11:28:35 PM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_Job` data isn't recorded at the parent business unit level -- only the business unit in which the send occurs.  I'd recommend dropping the `ent.` prefixes.

Comment: Too fast for me. I was just about to post the same answer, but saw the 'one new answer' alert.

Comment: Thanks Adam, that works.  
So, _Job exists at BU level but _Send can be at BU level and Enterprise?
It would be ideal to be able to pull in job details for all sends & all BUs, could this be done by sitting the page at Ent level?

Comment: That would be nice, but as far as I know, `_Job` is business unit specific.